# jquery slideshow navigation issue

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I am making a slideshow with two navigation elements (top and bottom). I have used a code several times but never in this way.

```
$('#list-links li a, #list-tab li a').hover(function(){
    $('#list-links li, #list-tab li').removeClass('hover');
    var i = $(this).index('#list-links li a, #list-tab li a');
    $(this).parent().addClass('hover');
    $('#slide-wrap').stop().animate({'marginLeft' : width*(-i)});
});
```

Basically this adds and removes a class (hover) to the list so that I can style accordingly. The problem is that it won´t work this way. The naviagtion becames independent, meaning that while navigation a) might be on the second slide, navigation b) doesn´t update and still has the hover class has if it would be on slide one. Can somebody help out?

Oh, the original full code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Declare variables
var width = 718; // width of slide - required for animation calculation
var slides = $('#list-images li');
var numSlides = slides.length;

// Wrap the slides & set the wrap width - this will be used to animate the slider left/right
slides.wrapAll('<div id="slide-wrap"></div>').css({'float' : 'left','width' : width});
$('#slide-wrap').css({width: width * numSlides});

// Hover function - animate the slides based on index of active link
$('#list-links li a').hover(function(){
    $('#list-links li').removeClass('hover');
    var i = $(this).index('#list-links li a');
    $(this).parent().addClass('hover');
    $('#slide-wrap').stop().animate({'marginLeft' : width*(-i)});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you also post your mark up?

I suspect that you can fix it by replacing this line:

```
$(this).parent().addClass('hover');
```

With this:

```
$('ul li:nth-of-type(' + (i+1) + ')').addClass('hover');
```

This will apply the hover class to the `li` at the correct index on both navigation bars.

**[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6QFK/)**

---

Also, when removing a class like this, I find it's a good practice to select it in a very general way, so that if anything was to go wrong when assigning the class, it will be fixed. Another good practice is to include that class in your selector, so that jQuery doesn't have to unnecessarily look at elements that don't have that class anyway.

```
$('ul li.hover').removeClass('hover');
```

---

**Source(s)**

http://api.jquery.com/index/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:nth-of-type

Comment: The code posted doesn´t seem to work for me `<ul id="list-tab"><li class="hover"><a href="#slide"></a></li><li><a href="#slide"></a></li><li><a href="#slide"></a></li></ul><ul id="list-images"><li>image1</li><li>image2</li><li>image3</li></ul><ul id="list-links"><li id="first"class="hover"><a href="#slide">1. Define your projects needs</a></li><li id="mid"><a href="#slide">2. Discover what you love style-wise</a></li><li id="last"><a href="#slide">3. Share it with your designer</a></li></ul>`

Comment: Ah, this is because I was selecting your `ul` by ID. I have replaced it with a `ul`, but you should add in a selector above it, maybe if it has a container?

Comment: it´s pretty close but now when I hover the second navigation I get the class on the first element. The first navigation shows nothing and the third adds the class on the second one.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that it is a zero based index. See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6QFK/)

Comment: Works very well except the animate I add now is not working well `$('#slide-wrap').stop().animate({'marginLeft' : width*(-i)`

Comment: You should try to read and understand code, not just copy and paste.. Because `.index()` is zero-based, I added 1 to it in the jsfiddle. Try `width*(-(i-1))`

Comment: well I just added the width of the slide in the end: `$('#slide-wrap').stop().animate({'marginLeft' : width*(-i)+ 718` Works great thank you